# Chart.js not linking in TypeScript dynamic web app

Tags: typescript, servlets, chart.js

I am building a dynamic web app in eclipse 2023-6 in (almost) 100 % typescript, no JS platforms like Angular/React etc. Server is tomcat 9.0, with java servlet. Server side and TS work fine until I try to add a chart package. I am trying to bring Chart.js into the app.

I used 'npm install chart.js --save' into a WebContent folder. In typescript I import Chart like this:

`import { Chart } from "/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"`

This gives "error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js'. '/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js' implicitly has an 'any' type."

I switch to /auto.js like this:

`import { Chart } from "/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js`

and it fixes this error.

Now I am ready to test the app with http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyApp

The console has 2 errors:

> GET http://localhost:8080/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> MyApp:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The '@kurkle' error is in chart.js. As I understand, chart.js is built for browser testing with node.js rather than with a server. Changing the path for @kurkle.... in chart.js fixes this error.

Here is a picture of the Eclipse project:

[image]

Here is the servlet:

```
package myApp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/MyApp")
public class MyApp extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public MyApp() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print ("<html><head><title>MyApp</title>");
        out.print ("<script type=\"module\" src=\"node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js\"></script>");     
        out.print ("</head><body>");
        out.print ("<script type=\"module\">");
        out.print ("import { test } from \"./test.js\";");
        out.print ("test()</script>");      
        out.print("<h2>This text from servlet</h2></body>");        
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here is the typescript code:`

```
import { Chart } from "/MyApp/WebContent/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js"
export function test(){
    console.log ("test() called");
    const testDiv:HTMLDivElement = <HTMLDivElement> document.createElement ("div");
    testDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>This text is from test.ts</h2>";
    
    const ctx:HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement ("canvas");
    testDiv.appendChild (ctx);
    
    const btn:HTMLButtonElement=<HTMLButtonElement>  document.createElement ("button");
    btn.addEventListener ("click", (ev:MouseEvent) => {console.log ("Do Chart clicked");
        
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
    });

    btn.textContent = 'Do Chart';
    testDiv.appendChild (btn);      
    document.body.appendChild (testDiv);
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",           
    "module": "ESNext", 
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",        
    "esModuleInterop": true,      
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,                           
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "../webapp"
  }
}
```

My first question is: what is the path for charts.js for the import in the typescript file, so the GET to the server will find it?

Next question: (am I allowed > 1?) does anyone have simple example of chart.js in a typescript/servlet app? I can't find anything.

Next question: the chart.js introduction says if you download the repo you must build it. When I ran "npm install chart.js --save" did I in fact download the repo? Chart.js strongly advises against this approach.

Comment: You have tried to load a js resource from the web root, but it should be loaded on bootstrap by the node.js which is not properly imported.